# Reduce queries that check if a user has completed a course

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have a course that contains of multiple lessons. On the course page I display all the lessons and an icon to indicate if a user has completed the course. I notices that (logically) Rails is querying the completions table for each lesson.

This is my Model method for checking if a user has completed a course:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
    def is_completed_by? current_user
      return true  if (current_user && self.completions.find_by(user: current_user))
      return false
    end
end
```

So I was thinking that it would be better to store a list of all completions by a user in a instance variable and check if the record exists in that collection. I've tried something like:

```
def is_completed_by? current_user
  @completed_list ||= Completion.where(user: current_user)
  return true  if (current_user && self.in?(@completed_list))
  return false
end
```

But this still triggers multiple queries. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Is `completions` a method that you have defined or an association and could you explain what it does

Comment: It's association to the user completeness model, sorry I omitted it from the model for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

`is_completed_by?` is an instance method of `Lesson` class. And `@completed_list` is an instance variable.

So each time you called the method in the loop, new query is triggered on each `lesson` instance.

Try to put the whole checking method or at least completed list to "persistent" (within the loop scope) object, current user for example.

```
class User
  def completed_list
    @completed_list ||= Completion.where(user: self)
  end
end


class Lesson
  def is_completed_by? current_user
    current_user && self.in?(current_user.completed_list))
  end
end
```

Comment: Still triggers the same amount of queries.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, was something different going on. This fixed my problem, thanks!

Comment: I removed this as the correct answer since this is comparing Lessons with Completions, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

`@completed_list` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and this is the reason that the query is invoked on each use. Try to convert it to an array:

```
@completed_list ||= Completion.where(user: current_user).to_a
```

However I think it is not a nice solution, much better is to use some caching manner, e.g.:

```
def is_completed_by? current_user
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/is_completed_by") do
    return true  if (current_user && self.completions.find_by(user: current_user))
    return false
  end
end
```

Yuou should remember to use `touch` method on the Lesson object if a completion has been added/updated.

Comment: But find_by would result in only one record being found, or am I wrong?